# Change ul li's order by drag&drop

Tags: javascript, html

So I've got some js code that's being executed every time an image is clicked.

```
images.forEach(function (image, index) {
    image.addEventListener('click', clicked);
})
let order_count = 0;

function clicked() {
    let selected = this.getAttribute('id');
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("li-item");
    li.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
    li.addEventListener("dragend", dragEnd);
    li.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter);
    li.addEventListener("dragleave", dragLeave);
    li.setAttribute("draggable", true);
    li.setAttribute("count", order_count);
    li.innerHTML = selected;
    list.append(li);
    order_count++;
    this.removeEventListener('click', clicked);
    this.children[0].remove();
}
```

What it does is that it forces clicked function to execute. In the click function I create li's and append them to ul, add 2 attributes of an integer and of draggable, add some class as well as event listeners for drag and drop. Those functions look as follows:

```
function dragStart() {
    this.classList.add("dragging");
    var start = this.getAttribute("count");
    console.log("dragstart element " + start);
}


function dragEnter() {
    var entered = this.getAttribute("count");
    this.classList.add("entered");
    console.log("drag entered element " + entered);
}


function dragLeave() {
    this.classList.remove("entered");
}


// drag end event
function dragEnd() {
    var final = this.getAttribute("count");
    console.log("dragend at element " + final);
    this.classList.remove("dragging");
}
```

The question is: how should I correctly specify the dragend function. Let's say, I want to start dragging the first element and put it on top of element five. I wish, that element 2 is now element 1, element 3 is now element 2 and so on. Wanna solve it in vanilla way only
Thanks for the help!